# .htaccess Rewrite subdomain to folder if existe

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain

I am trying to rewrite this url customer1.example.com to http://example.com/customer1.
With this code all works fine.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But if the **folder** customer2.example.com not exist in the root directori I would like to rewrite URL to root of example.com.

Condition 1 customer1.exemple.com => customer1 folder exist so rewrite to exemple.com/customer1.
Condition 2 customer2.exemple.com => customer2 folder not exist so rewrite to exemple.com

**The other think I need is that the rewrite reach only the example.com and not the other domain on my server.**

Thank you for help

Comment: _"But if the folder customer2.example.com not exist"_ - that is phrasing it wrongly, `sub.example.com` does not exist as a _folder_ either. What you want to check, is if the actual, physical _folder_ `customer2` (resp. `sub` in the other case) exists in your document root. So you will need to extract the subdomain part of the host name via a RewriteCond first, and then check if that matches an existing folder under your DR with a second one, that uses a back reference to the captured part from the first one.

Comment: Yes it is what I need, i will try to better explain.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

This will redirect to index.html on any not found page.

For subdomain redirection try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomains/sub/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you but this not work, I need to redirect only subdomain.exemple.com to exemple.com/subdomain or if subdomain directory not exist rewrite to exemple.com

Comment: Thank you, this is the likely the same as what I have. My probleme is how to rewrite to root http;//domain.com if sub folder not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I found the solution after a long search and tests...

Now for all subdomain requests .htaccess check if subdomain exist and if not try to rewrite to a folder in root domain and if not existe rewrite to root domain.

```
RewriteEngine On

#=============================
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/example.com/%1/ -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/%1/$1 [P,R=301]
#=============================
```

Now, I would like the redirection to be done normally but the url in the address bar does not change. like this :

```
https://example.com/foo => https://example.com
```

My websit is in this foo directories!

Thank you for help